# How do i get an int to work here without any problems? (Java)

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, bluej

I'm doing some work on a replica of the game mastermind in Java. For this i need the user to fill in squares with a color. Every round he has to fill in squares in an other layer. Like first the row on the bottom, second the one on top and so on...
I can't think of a solution in which I can fill the boxes without having to make an action listener for every button for every round... You don't have to give a solution, but maybe some Ideas how I could manage that? The code is written in the IDE BlueJ and in Java language.

```
if(runde == 1){
        faerbenSpieler(r1, p_s1_8, Color.RED,0,1);
        faerbenSpieler(g1, p_s1_8, Color.GREEN,0,2);
        faerbenSpieler(b1, p_s1_8, Color.BLUE,0,3);
        faerbenSpieler(t1, p_s1_8, tuerkis,0,4);

        faerbenSpieler(r2, p_s2_8, Color.RED,1,1);
        faerbenSpieler(g2, p_s2_8, Color.GREEN,1,2);
        faerbenSpieler(b2, p_s2_8, Color.BLUE,1,3);
        faerbenSpieler(t2, p_s2_8, tuerkis,1,4);

        faerbenSpieler(r3, p_s3_8, Color.RED,2,1);
        faerbenSpieler(g3, p_s3_8, Color.GREEN,2,2);
        faerbenSpieler(b3, p_s3_8, Color.BLUE,2,3);
        faerbenSpieler(t3, p_s3_8, tuerkis,2,4);
    }

private void faerbenSpieler(Button b, Panel p, Color c, int index, int wert)
{
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                p.setBackground(c);
                spieler[index]=wert;
            }
        });
}
```

How can I get the an int called "runde" in this to make for example the p_s1_8 to p_s1_7 ? So is there a thing how I can make the last bit of this change from 8 to 7 and to 6 and so on?
If I forgot something so you can't solve that let me know.
Thanks for answering :D
-Tobi

Comment: Try to find the duplication: You need to construct some component with a 4 color buttons for each choice. You need four such panels per round. But you don't need to name them all or retain variables to them, so each can be constructed anonymously by the same method repeatedly. Start grouping things that always occur together (such as Color and wert, and work from there.

Comment: Thanks @JoostPapendorp, I will try to group them!